# Line Integral with respect to x and y

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curves, line-integrals

In the example

Evaluate the line integral

\begin{equation}\int_C (x^2-2xy)dx + (y^2-2xy)dy \end{equation} where C is the parabola $y=x^2$ and -1 ≤ x ≤ 1

I paramterized the parabola to equal $r(t)= < t, t^2 >$ and then integrated with the following set up:

\begin{equation}\int_{-1}^1 (t^2-2t^3)dt + \int_{-1}^1 (t^4-2t^3)2t dt\end{equation}

when doing this I got an answer of $-14/15$.

I am not sure if it is correct because can a line integral be a negative value?
If not, can someone please point out where I went wrong?

Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3H8j.png

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Comment: Your result is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Why can’t the value be negative?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it could because isn't a line integral measuring the area under the field carved out by the curve? If so, how can that area be a negative value? Perhaps my understanding of line integrals is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my calculations, $-\frac{14}{15}$ is the correct answers.

For the second part of your question, line integrals can take negative values. Intuitively speaking, line integrals represent the (amount of) work done by a vector field.

So, your vector field in this case is doing work in the opposite direction to your line integral. You can also think of your solution as a tangent pointing in the opposite direction to you line integral.

I'd also suggest taking a look at Chapter 1 (Vector Analysis) of Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths. I think it provides a great intuition on Line, Surface, and Volume integrals.

Hope this helped!